# How to install dotnet core sdk in Debian Jessie

Tags: linux, debian, .net-core, debian-jessie

I'm having issues installing Dotnet Core SDK on my Debian Jessie Box.  This is the guide i've followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x.

After Registering the Product Key and Feed all i get is `Unable to locate Package` when trying to do an `apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0` or `dotnet-sdk-2.0.2`.  I'm currently logged in as root as this is my local dev machine.

**Steps to reproduce:**

```
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | gpg --dearmor > microsoft.gpg   
mv microsoft.gpg /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/microsoft.gpg  
sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/microsoft-debian-jessie-prod jessie main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list'  
apt-get update  
apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
```

> ```
> Reading package lists... Done   
> Building dependency tree  
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.0.0
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-2.0.0'
> ```

Where am i going wrong with this?  It's like apt cannot see the microsoft repo for some reason.
I realize i could just install this from a downloaded tarball and i will do that if necessary but my preference is to use the package manager for easy maintenance.

**Here is the output of apt-get update**

> ```
> root@myserver:/etc/apt# apt-get update
> Hit https://deb.nodesource.com jessie InRelease
> Hit https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Sources
> Hit https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main i386 Packages
> Get:1 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie InRelease [2,846 B]
> Get:2 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
> Get:3 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
> Get:4 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main amd64 Packages [6,069 B]
> Get:5 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
> Get:6 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [178 B]
> Get:7 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
> Get:8 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
> Get:9 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en [178 B]
> Get:10 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
> Get:11 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [178 B]
> Get:12 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
> Get:13 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en [178 B]
> Get:14 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
> Get:15 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [178 B]
> Get:16 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [162 B]
> Ign https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en_US
> Get:17 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en [178 B]
> Get:18 https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en [162 B]
> Ign https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Translation-en
> Get:19 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [178 B]
> Get:20 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en [178 B]
> Get:21 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en_US [178 B]
> Ign https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en_US
> Get:22 https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en [178 B]
> Ign https://packages.microsoft.com jessie/main Translation-en
> Fetched 8,915 B in 1s (5,969 B/s)
> Reading package lists... Done
> ```

Comment: Can you do an `sudo apt search dotnet`?. Also, can you retry-with `sudo apt-get install` rather than just `apt-get install`?

Comment: I'm logged in as root as this is my local dev box.
  
root@myserver:/etc/apt# apt search dotnet  
Sorting... Done  
Full Text Search... Done

Comment: Can you include the output of `apt-get update` in the question?

Comment: What happens if you do an `apt-cache search dotnet` and `apt-cache search dotnet-sdk` ?

Comment: Both apt-cache search dotnet and dotnet-sdk return no results!

Comment: I was having much the same issue then I upgraded to Debian Stretch and had no problems.  Follow @AdamH409 post below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After fighting with this for days i decided to upgrade my box to Debian Stretch. 
Here is the article i followed https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch

> apt-get update
>   apt-get upgrade
>   apt-get dist-upgrade

Changed my sources.list

```
FROM JESSIE  
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie main  
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-updates main  
deb http://security.debian.org jessie/updates main  
TO STRETCH  
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch main  
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian stretch-updates main  
deb http://security.debian.org stretch/updates main
```

Ran this again

> apt-get update
>   apt-get upgrade
>   apt-get dist-upgrade

After the upgrade completed i was able to finally see the dotnet core packages i was looking for!

Comment: I'm still having this issue, what could be the reason? the microsoft instructions are the following:
https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/linux-package-manager/debian9/sdk-current

Answer (score 0):

Another reason this might not be working for you is if you are running a 32 bit version of linux.  Dot Net Core Packages are only available for 64 bit.  I ran into this gotcha as well when nothing was coming up when trying to install on a 32 bit version of Debian.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x